# Hive mysql connector error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have installed Hive and mysql successfully, i did the configuration for Hive as suggested in [link](http://doctuts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hive.html). But i see an error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
..
..
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
```

so i added the mysql-connector-java.jar in lib of Hive. Now hive just hangs, i dont get the shell at all.

Kindly suggest how i can resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add mysql connector to the classpath in the hive. It is looking for that connector in your classpath and its not able to find it. Download mysql connector and put it to the following path

```
/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib
```

Comment: Thats what am telling putting the mysql connector in Hive lib path did not work. kindly suggest how i can resolve this issue and am using 1.1.0 version so i see all folders like lib,conf,bin,hcatalog, etc., under /usr/lib/hive and i dont have a folder like apache-hive-0.13.0-bin or apache-hive-1.1.0-bin.